# Is the the word (problems) a subject or object of gerund?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the function of the noun **problems** in this sentence?

Is it a subject or object of gerund ?

> Solving the water **problems** in this way is hard.

Similarly in this sentence:

> Writing **fiction** requires a lot of talent.

Is the noun **fiction** a subject? Or otherwise, the subject here is the gerund **writing** and fiction is just an object of gerund?

Comment: Gerund phrases can easily be confused with participle phrases. https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund-phrase/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Solving the water problems in this way is very hard.
  **problem** is a direct object of solve

The subject is: solving the water problems
in this way is an adverbial phrase that is not part of the subject per se

- Writing fiction requires a lot of talent.
  **fiction** is a direct object of write.
  The subject is: writing fiction

Those are gerund phrases or nouns used as subjects.

> A gerund phrase is a phrase consisting of a gerund and any modifiers
> or ***objects associated with it***. A gerund is a noun made from a verb
> root plus ing (a present participle). A whole gerund phrase functions
> in a sentence just like a noun, and can act as a subject, an object,
> or a predicate nominative.

[gerund phrase or noun acting as a subject](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund-phrase/)

[Please note: I use simple language to describe this as appropriate for language learners]